# How to use RxJS in Vuex module

Tags: typescript, vue.js, rxjs, axios, vuex-modules

I created an API service that is used by an auth service, which is used by a Vuex module. In my sign-in component, I use the Vuex module to communicate with the API, but the call does not wait for the API response.

*API service:*

```
class ApiService {
  protected readonly api = 'https://xxx.yzz:44310/api'
  private static instance: ApiService
  private headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }

  constructor() {
    this.init()
  }

  private init() {
    Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)
    Vue.axios.defaults.baseURL = this.api
  }

  public static get Instance() {
    return this.instance || (this.instance = new this())
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {
    const applicationError = error.headers['Application-Error']
    return Observable.throw(modelStateErrors || 'Server error')
  }

  get(path: string, params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams()):     Observable<any> {
    return from(axios.get(`${path}`, { params })).pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
  }

  put(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable<any> {
    return from(axios.put(`${path}`,     JSON.stringify(body))).pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
  }

  post(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable<any> {
    return from(
      axios.post(`${path}`, JSON.stringify(body), {
        headers: this.headers
      })
    ).pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
  }



export const apiService = ApiService.Instance
```

*Authorization service:*

```
class AuthService {
  private static instance: AuthService

  private constructor() {}

  public static get Instance() {
    return this.instance || (this.instance = new this())
  }

  public login(credentials: Credentials): Observable<any> {
    return apiService.post('/auth/login', credentials).pipe(map(result => result.data))
  }
}

export const authService = AuthService.Instance
```

*Vuex module with the authorization method:*

```
import { Module, VuexModule, Mutation, Action } from 'vuex-module-decorators'
import { Credentials } from '@/core/models/credentials.interface'
import { authService } from '@/core/services/auth.service'
import { Usuario } from '@/core/models/usuario.interface'

@Module
export default class Auth extends VuexModule {
  count = 0
  usuario: Usuario | null = null
  isAuthenticated: boolean = false

  @Mutation
  setUsuario(usuario: Usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario
    this.isAuthenticated = true
  }

  @Action({})
  public authRequest(credentials: Credentials) {
    return authService.login(credentials).subscribe(
      (usuario: Usuario) => {
        this.context.commit('setUsuario', usuario)
      },
      (errors: any) => {
        console.log('errors', JSON.stringify(errors))
      }
    )
  }
}
```

In my sign-in component, I use the Vuex module as follows:

```
  onSubmit() {
    (this.$refs.userCredentials as any).validate((valid: boolean) => {
      if (valid) {
        this.$store
          .dispatch('authRequest', this.userCredentials)
          .then(() => {
            this.$router.push('/');
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
          });
      } else {
        console.log('error submit!!');
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
```

The result I expect is that when I press the login button, the code waits until the API responds, and depending on the result, takes the next steps.

Comment: Vuex actions typically expect a literal or `Promise` as a return. In `Auth.authRequest()`, try changing the return to a `Promise` with [`toPromise`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html).

Answer (score 0):

`authRequest` is returning a `Subscription` but to use `.then` the `onSubmit` logic is expecting a `Promise` type here. You may want to use `.tap`/`.do` followed by a `.toPromise` in the `authRequest`

Comment: Franco, is there other to use instead of .then?

Comment: I would suggest just do a `tap` in the service function (remove the `.subscribe`) and chain `.subscribe` instead of `.then` in the `onSubmit ` method

Answer (score -1):

Yeah you're returning a subscription in the action, which you don't want to do. Replace .subscribe with .pipe(shareReplay()) in your action. Observable implements PromiseLike, so you might be fine with just that. If that still doesn't work, you'll have to call .toPromise() at the end of the return statement in the action. A vuex-rxjs library would be a beautiful thing, I wish I had the time to do it. Hopefully someone else does soon :)